# Как разбить вывод из mysql постранично

Tags: php

Приведите хороший пример!

Comment: google -> pagination

Answer (score 1):

Я когда-то учился на этом примере: [постраничная навигация](http://www.softtime.ru/article/index.php?id_article=33).

Answer (score 1):

Приведу код функции, которую недавно писал для одного Open Source проекта
$per_page - число записей на страницу.
$page - номер страницы
$total_rows - общее число записей

```
 function paging(){
        global $per_page,$page,$common_get,$calendar_url,$title,$total_rows;
        $per_page=(int)$per_page;
        $page=(int)$page;

        $count=$total_rows;

        if ($per_page==1){
            $pages=1;
        } else {
            $pages = ceil($count/$per_page);
        }
        if ($page < 1) {
            $page = 1;
        }
        elseif ($page > $pages) {
            $page = $pages;
        }
        $neighbours = 2;
        $left_neighbour = $page - $neighbours;
        if ($left_neighbour < 1) $left_neighbour = 1;

        $right_neighbour = $page + $neighbours;
        if ($right_neighbour > $pages) $right_neighbour = $pages;
            echo '<div id="paging">';
            if ($pages!=1){ echo '
                <div id="pages"><ul>';
                if ($page > 1) {
                    print ' <li><a href="'.$calendar_url.'index.php?'.$common_get.'&page=1">&lt;&lt;</a></li><li><a href="'.$calendar_url.'index.php?'.$common_get.'&page=' . ($page-1) . '">&lt;</a></li> ';
                }
                for ($i=$left_neighbour; $i<=$right_neighbour; $i++) {
                    if ($i != $page) {
                        print ' <li><a href="'.$calendar_url.'index.php?'.$common_get.'&page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li> ';
                    }
                    else {
                        print ' <li><span>' . $i . '</span></li> ';
                    }
                }

                if ($page < $pages) {
                    print '<li><a href="'.$calendar_url.'index.php?'.$common_get.'&page=' . ($page+1) . '">&gt;</a></li><li><a href="'.$calendar_url.'index.php?'.$common_get.'&page=' . $pages . '">&gt;&gt</a></li>';
                }

                echo '</ul></div>';
    }
        echo '
        <div class="events-for-page">';

            echo '<p>Events per page:</p>';

        echo '<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="pagesh" value="1" />';

        echo '
            <select name="pages" id="pages">';
                $selected='';
                if ($per_page==1){$selected='selected="selected"';} else {$selected='';}
                echo '<option '.$selected.' value="1">All</option>';
                if ($per_page==5){$selected='selected="selected"';} else {$selected='';}
                echo '<option '.$selected.' value="5">5</option>';
                    if ($per_page==10){$selected='selected="selected"';} else {$selected='';}
                echo '<option '.$selected.' value="10">10</option>';
                    if ($per_page==20){$selected='selected="selected"';} else {$selected='';}
                echo '<option '.$selected.' value="20">20</option>';
                    if ($per_page==50){$selected='selected="selected"';} else {$selected='';}
                echo '<option '.$selected.' value="50">50</option>';

            echo '</select>
            <input type="submit" value="Go"/>';

        echo '
        </form>
        </div>
        <p>Total Events: '.$count.'</p>
        </div>';
    }
```

В другом скрипте где формируется sql запрос надо прописать следующее:
$per_page - из формы с функции paging(), сохраняю значение в сессии.
$page = из параметров $_GET.

```
$q='SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `table`';
    if ($per_page!=1){
                    $start = ($page-1)*$per_page;
                    $limit=' LIMIT '.$start.','.$per_page;
                    $q.=$limit;
                }
```

Найти общее число записей поможет функция SQL - FOUND_ROWS()